# Python CSV Import taking too much time after first 200k rows

Tags: python, mysql, import-csv

I have a python import script that imports a CSV.
It takes around 45 seconds to import 20k rows into a mysql db.
The problem is that now I have a huge file (4 million rows), and it is taking like 200 seconds to import those same 20k rows when it reaches the line ~200k of the file.

I dont know if thats some DB issue or the file reading itself... here is my script:

```
import csv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import argparse
from itertools import islice

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
args = parser.parse_args() 



def parseData(row):
    sql = """INSERT INTO TABLE 
    (column1,column2) 
    VALUES( '%s','%s');""" % (
        row['col1'],row['col2'],) 


    return sql


def dataImport(filename,connection,cursor):
        data = csv.DictReader(filename,delimiter=';')
        i = 0 
        for row in data:
            sql = parseData(row)
            try:
                result = cursor.execute(sql)
                pass
            except Error as e:
                    pass 

            if i%20000 == 0: 
                connection.commit()

            i=i+1

def importa(file):

    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host=host,
                                            database=db,
                                            user=user,
                                            password=password)

        if connection.is_connected():
            db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
            print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)

            cursor = connection.cursor()
            dataImport(file,connection,cursor)

            cursor.close()


    except Error as e:
        print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    importa(args.file)
```

Comment: It might help to use `executemany` to do single inserts of 20K rows instead of committing 20K insert statements. I don't use mysql but I've found a similar method speeds up PostgreSQL. The code to do it is just a bit past the middle of this page. https://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table/

Comment: @Deepstop thanks for the suggestion, I will try it and let you know

Comment: @Deepstop it did improve drastically my import speed (now it takes 4s for 20k!), but for the row after ~200k it is taking around 2500 seconds for 20k.... any idea?

Comment: Something to do with indexing maybe? Could you add the schema of TABLE to your post? Also if you are moving each 200K chunk to a list before `executemany` then you could use `time.time()`to determine if it's the `csv` file or the `insert` that is slow but I suspect the latter. However, can I also suggest that unless there's a compelling reason otherwise to stop using `DictReader` and just use `reader` with numeric indexes which should cut down some overhead on the client side if you haven't already done that.

Comment: The issue now is on the database, its lagging after those thousand rows.... funny thing is that its not lagging when the file start processing, even if the table volume is huge..... weird.... I used time to measure the transactions time, tks!

Comment: One other thing you could try is to close the cursor and create a new one each time. I'm clutching at straws here. Other than that it is probably running out of some resource at the server end. Are you still committing every 20K rows?

Comment: @Deepstop yes, I will update the code now that I am using executemany! Tks

Comment: @Deepstop it does look like a database issue. I will accept your answer, if you want to write it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `executemany` to do single inserts of 20K rows instead of 20K individual `INSERT` statements will optimize the transfer, but the database itself could also be a factor in the slow performance. There is a code example just a bit past the middle of [this page](http://pynative.com/python-mysql-insert-data-into-database-table).

Based on our exchange of comments, the database is the ultimate culprit in the slow performance. One idea that I've seen is to disable indexing until after everything is loaded.

```
ALTER TABLE table DISABLE KEYS;
... executemany called a bunch of times...
ALTER TABLE table ENABLE KEYS;
```

That might be worth a try.